# Alinhamento menu drop down

Tags: html, css

tenho uma barra de navegação horizontal, que possui submenus. Atualmente o submenu está ficando alinhado à esquerda do menu ao qual ele pertence. Como nessa imagem:

[image: Menu atual]

Eu gostaria que o submenu ficasse alinhado à direita do menu ao qual ele pertence. Como nessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou utilizando para criar esse menu está aqui (O html e css estão em um arquivo único):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
         }
        body{
            font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .menu{
            list-style:none;
            border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
            float:right;
        }
        .menu li{
            position:relative;
            float:right;
            border-right:1px solid #c0c0c0;
        }

        .menu li a{
            color:#333; 
            text-decoration:none; 
            padding:5px 10px; 
            display:block;
        }

        .menu li a:hover{
            background:#333;
            color:#fff;
            -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
            text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff;
        }
        .menu li  ul{
            position:absolute;
            top:25px;
            left:0;
            background-color:#fff;
            display:none;
        } 

        .menu li:hover ul, .menu li.over ul{
            display:block;
        }

        .menu li ul li{
            border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
            display:block;
            width:150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li> <a>Nome aleatorio</a> </li>
        <li>
            <a>Bruno Pinheiro</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Editar Perfil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta mudar de `left: 0;` para `right: 0;` na linha que refiro neste pedaço do CSS:

```
.menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;   /*   Mude aqui... para right: 0;   */
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
```

#### E o resultado será: http://jsfiddle.net/uuu5ttek/

Comment: Muito obrigado Sergio. Era justamente isso que eu precisava.